# (Javax swing) repaint() sometimes not calling paintComponent()

Tags: java, swing

I tried to find a question that answers my problem but could not find any since the questions asked are about that repaint() is never called

My problem is that when i start the application it either works without problems, or that **only** paintComponent() is not called (there are no errors)

My code:
GamePanel.java:

```
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1819637299730865623L;

    private Timer time;
    private long oldTime;
    private int Width;
    private int Height;


    public GamePanel(int Width, int Height) {
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        oldTime = System.nanoTime();
        setup();
        System.console().printf("Begin!");
        time = new Timer(0,this);
        time.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update(((float)(System.nanoTime() - oldTime)) / (float)1000000000);
        System.console().printf("Running!");
        oldTime = System.nanoTime();
        repaint();
        time.start();
    }





    float x = 0;
    float del;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.console().printf("Drawing!");
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Width, Height);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,0,255));
        g.fillOval((int)x-40,60,80,80);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        g.drawString(Float.toString(1 / del), Width / 2, Height / 2);

        g.dispose();
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        x += delta * 50;
        del = delta;
    }

    public void setup() {

    }
```

Renderer.java (this is created in the main function)

```
    public class Renderer {
    int Height, Width;
    JFrame obj;
    GamePanel pan;

    public Renderer(int Width, int Height, int StartposX, int StartposY, String title) {
        obj = new JFrame();
        this.Height = Height;
        this.Width = Width;

        obj.setBounds(StartposX,StartposY,Width,Height);
        obj.setTitle(title);
        obj.setResizable(false);
        obj.setVisible(true);
        obj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pan = new GamePanel(Width,Height);
        obj.add(pan);
    }

}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the output i get is:
Begin!Running!Running!Running!...
or
Begin!Running!Drawing!Running!Drawing!...

Comment: This `g.dispose();` is dangerous code -- delete that line ***immediately***!  Also, be sure to call `super.paintComponent(g);` on the first line of your override.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or [mre] where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: This, `Timer(0,this);` is not realistic. No Timer can loop instantaneously. Give the timer delay a reasonable value, say 12 or 13 msecs.

Comment: This definetly decreased the amount of white screens i get but i still get a white screen every ~10 tries, with the same output

Comment: in the description of timer() it says that if you insert 0 as the delay it will run instantly

Comment: There is nothing that says every `repaint()` calls `paintComponent()`. The repaint manager collects the repaints and paints when it feels like it. If you get white screens, it may be because you have not done what Hovercraft told you to.

Comment: Calling repaint() queues a request to repaint the component. If ,you call repaint() when the system already has a repaint request queued (but not yet executed), then the earlier requests will most likely be expunged from the queue and only the most recent request will actually cause a call to painComponent().

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem all that one has to do is:
remove

```
    g.dispose();
```

add

```
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

at paintComponent()
and add

```
    obj.setVisible(true);
```

after obj.add(pan);

Comment: Do you understand *why* those are needed?  A program must never call dispose() on a Graphics object that the program itself did not create.  The Graphics objects passed to paint methods are created by AWT/Swing and owned by AWT/Swing.  They are not yours to dispose of.  The need for super.paintComponent is described in [the custom painting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I run your whole code adding a main() method in the Renderer.java to be able to test it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Renderer(300, 300, 10, 10, "Testing Renderer");
        }
    });
}
```

You code program runs fine if I removed all the System.console().printf codes.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe it does work, but the original code as posted is not correct for a properly written paintComponent(…) method. The suggestions provided by the OP are correct. 1) You should invoke super.paintComponent(…) first to make sure the background is cleared. 2) You should NOT dispose of a Graphics object you do not create. Since the Graphics object is passed to the method it is incorrect to dispose of it.

Comment: My answer is not a perfect solution. The OP should also consider your comment.